# Searching for Arabic Language Pack that supports Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, language, locale

I have installed magento 1.9.2.4 and a paid theme. Now only arabic language pack needed which supports this version. So far unable to find it so please help.

Thank you

Comment: Please use (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-arabic-standard-language-pack.html), it will working in your version

Comment: I tried to install this extension but an error came and server went down :(

Comment: Please explain what type of error?

Comment: Checking dependencies of packages
Starting to download Locale_Mage_community_ar_MA-1.0.19870.4.8-beta.tgz ...

CONNECT ERROR: Package not found: Locale_Mage_community_ar_MA 1.0.19870.4.8-beta

Answer (score 1):

- language Package : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-arabic-saudi-arabia-language-pack.html get key
- Admin panel ->system-> Magento Connect install new language package.
- admin panel-> system-> Configuration -chose you Current Configuration Scope -General -> Locale Options set :Locale Arabic (Saudi Arabia) or your arabic package you chose (Egypt , Morocco ..etc)
- admin panel -> system -> Cache Management : Flush Magento Cache
- refresh front page for your store

Good luck... :)

Comment: The link is redirecting me to this: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

Where I can't find any saudi arab language pack :(

Comment: check this `https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/tree/master/app/locale` here you will find all the language package

Comment: Ill download and test

Comment: Its not supporting magento 1.9.2.4 :( some error came that package is not there etc

Comment: I downloaded this one: https://web.archive.org/web/20140713083001/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/44

But error came now my site is down giving server error :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the only working Arabic translation on the 
https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/

There's also repository on GitHub https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/ , but I don't see ar_SA locale there.

Comment: How to install it? I need arabic for frontend, RTL already installed in it.

Comment: You need to unpack archive and you will find ``app/locale/ar_SA`` there, copy ar_SA folder to your website ``app/locale`` folder. Then within admin you need to go to System -> Configuration -> General. When you need to select Locale - Arabic (Saudi Arabia).

Comment: My client site has both english and arabic language option on top right:

https://arabianglitz.com/

So by doing this site will convert to arabic only.. plz guide

Comment: Then on configuration page you need to switch site scope, on the left top you will find Current Configuration Scope, change default value to your Arabic store and then select Arabic locale.

Comment: Where to put app\design from ar_SA folder?

As my present as_SA folder have a template folder and lots of csv files.

Please guide

Comment: There's not much of translation inside app/design, main thing is to put app/locale/ar_SA.

Comment: I did that but still no luck :( just few text is converting into arabic:

Please check: https://arabianglitz.com/

Comment: Correct, your theme words you need to translate additionally. You can use inline translate feature for that http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-use-translate-inline-feature.html , then you need to translate blocks and other things http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-translate-the-text-which-is-not-affected-by-the-magento-inline-translation-tool.html . Please accept my answer, thanks.

Comment: It didn't help :( Tell me if I can integrate google translator with RTL?